# Android Thumbnail Size Practice

Tags: android, thumbnails, image-scaling

I implemented a ListView with a AsyncTask for image loading and resizing. My question is about the image size of thumbnails for different Android Screen sizes. 
If I shrink my thumbnails to 100px width and height, all my images have best sizes in every screen size. This means all my thumbnails have the same size. Does Android scale images internal?
I want to display a placeholder for all my list items if they have no own image.
I know this question is a little bit confusing but what i mean is:
Should i shrink my images to only one size and bring no placeholder for each screen size to have no different thumbnail sizes or scale my images by individual screen sizes and use a fallback from my ldpi, mdpi, hdpi or xhdpi? I hope it is understandable.

Comment: I have difficulties understanding, what you are saying. What has scaling images has to do with a placeholder? or am I missing something? Do you *want* them(the thumbnails) to be exact the same size on ervy screen? or do you want them to be relatively big compared to the listsize, TVs etc?... also I wouldn't use px. Use dip's istead

Comment: I mean with a placeholder a default image for list items which comes with my app from ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi folder.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so your question is if you should provide an placeholder in all densitys? You can, but its not necessary. Coincidentally  we just discussed that on tze android chat site here on stackoverflow. A user tested it out weather its necessary to provide images lower than hdpi. He tested it out and he noticed that Android resized all drawables just perfect so you wouldn't see a different. I hope I could answer your question.